# CodeIgniter - accessing $this scope from ajax

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

A project I'm updating was written in CodeIgniter.  I am trying to pull information from the database using the standard CI methods of...

```
$this->db->select('myfield')...
```

However, $this is not defined in my ajax page.  It is a separate simple PHP page that is just going to pull the info I need and return a HTML table of the contents.

How can I access $this from the ajax script?  I have a function in my model file too, and I have tried to access it from the ajax script using

```
$this->my_model->myfunction();
```

but that fails as well.  CodeIgniter is version 2.1.2

Comment: You need to put your code into a *controller* function.  That way, it has access to `$this` and the rest of the CodeIgniter stuff.  Then send the AJAX request to `/controller/funcname` (like any other CodeIgniter page).

Comment: @RocketHazmat how do I send an argument to the function like that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - nevermind I got it.  If you want to mark your comment as answer I will accept. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to access CodeIgniter's methods and its `$this` object is to be inside of a controller function.

Don't make a standalone PHP page, instead make a controller (or a new function in an existing controller) and send your AJAX request to there.  You can send POST variables and access then via `$this->input->post('var')`.